# Why does DSolve not yield a solution to this coupled differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I am having 16 coupled equations that I try to solve using `DSolve`.
However, when running my notebook, the Kernel keeps running for over 30 mins, so there might be an error somewhere. I *know* that there is an analytic solution to the set of equations, and I also know that I can't solve them by hand. I checked the equations for typos for multiple hours and I really think that there is no typo in there anymore.

What I tried:

1. Specified that my input parameters are real
2. Solved the coupled equations without the imaginary part, which gives the solution I am looking for.
3. If I add the imaginary part, something goes wrong.

Maybe someone here immediately sees an error!

````
$Assumptions = \[Omega] \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals

eqns = {r11'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r11[t] - r22[t] - r33[t]), 
      r22'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r22[t] - r11[t] - r44[t]),
      r33'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r33[t] - r44[t] - r11[t]),
      r44'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r44[t] - r33[t] - r22[t]), 
      r12'[t] == 
    I*\[Omega]*r12[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r12[t] - r21[t] - r34[t]), 
      r13'[t] == 
    I*\[Omega]*r13[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r13[t] - r24[t] - r31[t]), 
      r14'[t] == 
    2*I*\[Omega]*r14[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r14[t] - r23[t] - r32[t]), 
      r21'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r21[t] - 
     1/2*a*(2*r21[t] - r12[t] - r43[t]), 
      r23'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r23[t] - r41[t] - r14[t]), 
      r24'[t] == 
    I*\[Omega]*r24[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r24[t] - r13[t] - r42[t]),
      r31'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r31[t] - 
     1/2*a*(2*r31[t] - r42[t] - r13[t]),
      r32'[t] == 1/2*a*(2*r32[t] - r41[t] - r14[t]),
      r34'[t] == 
    I*\[Omega]*r34[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r34[t] - r43[t] - r12[t]),
      r41'[t] == -2*I*\[Omega]*r41[t] - 
     1/2*a*(2*r41[t] - r32[t] - r23[t]),
      r42'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r42[t] - 
     1/2*a*(2*r42[t] - r31[t] - r24[t]),
      r43'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r43[t] - 
     1/2*a*(2*r43[t] - r34[t] - r21[t]),    
      
   r11[0] == 0, r22[0] == 1/2, r33[0] == 1/2, r44[0] == 0, 
   r12[0] == 0, r13[0] == 0, r14[0] == 0, r21[0] == 0, r23[0] == 1/2, 
   r24[0] == 0, r31[0] == 0, r32[0] == 1/2, r34[0] == 0, r41[0] == 0, 
   r42[0] == 0, r43[0] == 0};

sol = DSolve[
  eqns, {r11, r12, r13, r14, r22, r33, r44, r21, r23, r24, r31, r32, 
   r34, r41, r42, r43}, t]
```
````

Comment: Though this may not be an answer you want to get, simply the system may be too complicated for Mathematica to automatically handle. If you set `\[Omega]` and `a` to certain numbers (say, both are `1`), then `DSolve` and `NDSolve` work well.

Comment: I don't think 30 minutes is long enough if there are no typos and there is an analytic solution that can be solved manually.  I'd wait at least 4 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This system can be solved using `LaplaceTransform`.  The first step is to separate the system into a list of ODEs and a list of initial conditions:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eqnt = {r11'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r11[t] - r22[t] - r33[t]), 
   r22'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r22[t] - r11[t] - r44[t]), 
   r33'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r33[t] - r44[t] - r11[t]), 
   r44'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r44[t] - r33[t] - r22[t]), 
   r12'[t] == I*\[Omega]*r12[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r12[t] - r21[t] - r34[t]), 
   r13'[t] == I*\[Omega]*r13[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r13[t] - r24[t] - r31[t]), 
   r14'[t] == 2*I*\[Omega]*r14[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r14[t] - r23[t] - r32[t]), 
   r21'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r21[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r21[t] - r12[t] - r43[t]),
   r23'[t] == -1/2*a*(2*r23[t] - r41[t] - r14[t]), 
   r24'[t] == I*\[Omega]*r24[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r24[t] - r13[t] - r42[t]), 
   r31'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r31[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r31[t] - r42[t] - r13[t]),
   r32'[t] == 1/2*a*(2*r32[t] - r41[t] - r14[t]), 
   r34'[t] == I*\[Omega]*r34[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r34[t] - r43[t] - r12[t]), 
   r41'[t] == -2*I*\[Omega]*r41[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r41[t] - r32[t] - r23[t]), 
   r42'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r42[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r42[t] - r31[t] - r24[t]),
   r43'[t] == -I*\[Omega]*r43[t] - 1/2*a*(2*r43[t] - r34[t] - r21[t])};
ics = {r11[0] == 0, r22[0] == 1/2, r33[0] == 1/2, r44[0] == 0, 
   r12[0] == 0, r13[0] == 0, r14[0] == 0, r21[0] == 0, r23[0] == 1/2, 
   r24[0] == 0, r31[0] == 0, r32[0] == 1/2, r34[0] == 0, r41[0] == 0, 
   r42[0] == 0, r43[0] == 0};
```

The next steps are to transform the equations, to apply the initial conditions, to solve for the transforms (`vars`) and to transform back.

```
eqns = LaplaceTransform[eqnt, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ics;
vars = Cases[eqns, _LaplaceTransform, ∞] // DeleteDuplicates;
soln = Solve[eqns, vars] // Flatten;
rsoln = InverseLaplaceTransform[soln, s, t];
```

The 16 solutions for the functions $r_{ij}(t)$ given in the list `rsoln` fall into three categories.  Eight of the solutions are trivial.  Four of the solutions are independent of $\omega$.  The remaining four solutions may have imaginary parts.

```
trivial = Select[rsoln, Last[#] == 0 &];
freeω = Select[Complement[rsoln, trivial], FreeQ[#, ω] &];
others = Complement[rsoln, trivial, freeω];
```

For real, positive $a$, the solutions that are independent of $\omega$ decay exponentially.

```
f = freeω /. a -> 1 // Values;
Plot[f, {t, 0, π}]
```

[image]

The solutions with imaginary parts can also be plotted for specific values of $\omega$ and $a$

```
g = others /. ω -> 1 /. a -> -1 // Values;
ReImPlot[g, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> {All, {-20, 20}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One follow-up: Is there a way to simplifiy the 4 equations in `others`? For example, $r_{14}$ has the solution $r_{14} = \frac{a}{2}e^{-at}\left(\frac{2 i \omega[\cosh(\Omega t) - 1]}{\Omega^2} + \frac{\sinh(\Omega t)}{\Omega}\right)$, $\Omega = \sqrt{a^2 - 4\omega^2}$. In particular, I care about $r_{32}(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-a t} \frac{a^2 \cosh(\Omega t) - 4\omega^2}{\Omega^2}$

Comment: Also, I made a sign error: It's `r32'[t] = -1/2*a* (....)`, not `+`.

Comment: Nevermind, an application of `FullSimplify[others]` did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ODEs are linear with constant coefficients, `DSolve` must be able to solve them, although perhaps slowly.  Here we provide a quick approach.

With the array of 16 ODEs (but not the initial conditions) set to `eqns`, `DSolve` finds a solution in seconds.

```
sol = First@DSolve[eqns, {r11[t], r12[t], r13[t], r14[t], r22[t], r33[t], 
    r44[t], r21[t], r23[t], r24[t], r31[t], r32[t], r34[t], r41[t], 
    r42[t], r43[t]}, t, Assumptions -> ω ∈ Reals && a ∈ Reals];
```

although `sol` is far too long to reproduce here.  Next evaluate the initial conditions,

```
sol /. t -> 0;
{r11[0] == 0, r22[0] == 1/2, r33[0] == 1/2, r44[0] == 0, 
    r12[0] == 0, r13[0] == 0, r14[0] == 0, r21[0] == 0, r23[0] == 1/2, 
    r24[0] == 0, r31[0] == 0, r32[0] == 1/2, r34[0] == 0, r41[0] == 0, 
    r42[0] == 0, r43[0] == 0} /. %;
% // Simplify;
Array[C, 16];
solc = FullSimplify[ToRadicals@Flatten@Solve[%%, %], 
    Assumptions -> ω ∈ Reals && a ∈ Reals]
(* {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1/2, C[3] -> 1/2, C[4] -> 0, C[5] -> 0, C[6] -> 0,
    C[7] -> 0, C[8] -> 0, C[9] -> 0, C[10] -> 0, C[11] -> 0, C[12] -> 0,
    C[13] -> 0, C[14] -> 1/2, C[15] -> 1/2, C[16] -> 0} *)
```

(My thanks to [Akku14](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34287/akku14) for pointing out the simplification above in `solc`.)  Finally,

```
sode = Simplify[sol /. solc]
```

gives the desired solution.  The simpler solutions are given by

```
{r11[t], r22[t], r33[t], r44[t]} /. sode
(* {1/4 - 1/4 E^(-2 a t), 1/4 (1 + E^(-2 a t)), 1/4 (1 + E^(-2 a t)), 
    1/4 - 1/4 E^(-2 a t)} *)
{r12[t], r21[t], r34[t], r43[t], r13[t], r24[t], r31[t], r42[t]} /. sode
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

and `{r13, r14, r15, r16}` involve lengthy `Root` functions.

Comment: to @bbgodfrey,   with ` // ToRadicals // 
 FullSimplify[#, 
   Assumptions -> \[Omega] \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals] & `  you can show C[14] and C[15] to be == 1/2 both.

Comment: @Akku14 Thank you.